# Как отправить сообщение на другой ресурс

Tags: jquery, php, алгоритм

Нужен алгоритм данной задачи, т.е. план написания скрипта, шаблон:

[image]

Пункт **А** — это мой сайт, где поддерживается PHP, CURL, Perl, MySQL и все остальное, а также хостинг без ограничений. В других пунктах (1,2,3 и т.д.) не поддерживается PHP и вышеуказанные программы, и есть ограничения. Это сайты Ucoz (CMS).

**Задача:**  На сайтах Ucoz будет определенный блок, который будет доступен для просмотра, только администраторам, и нужно в этот блок, отправлять сообщения из **А**  (мой сайт), и удалять сообщения после прочтения.

Вроде бы задача не трудная. Как я себе представляю:

- Создам файл `message.php`, где будет сообщение, и на сайтах ucoz, через $.getScript проверять при каждом входе администратора на сайт.

Сходу у меня ничего не получилось. Прошу, дайте идею насчет реализации данной задачи. Я много написал, может, вам будет непонятно, но я могу ответить на все вопросы, только помогите с алгоритмом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немножко субьективный ответ, но опишу, как это было бы удобнее для меня:

1. Страница `message.php` возвращает ответ в формате `json`, вызывая при этом `callback`-функцию в `js` коде страницы — так будет удобнее обрабатывать ответ.
2. При нажатии на кнопку "удалить" (или при прочтении, значения не имеет), вызывается `message.php?delete`, удаляя при этом контент.

И, учитывая любовь `ucoz` к `ajax`-запросам, лучше сделать это "по старинке", через `iframe`.

Вроде как всё просто и логично, что именно у вас не получается?

**upd:** извините, не заметил предыдущий ответ.

Comment: вариант с iframe для ucoz будет лучше , но тогда появляется возможно разного вида атак , на подобие http://learn.javascript.ru/clickjacking , но если автора не пугает, то встроить iframe будет проще)

Comment: @Crasher, вариант с iframe, думаю будет правильно, но, как я отправлю данные сайту ucoz о том, что - "есть новое сообщение"? создать файл с json?   и через iframe отправлять ответ?  - по моему Ajax запросы в ucoz ограничен, когда запросы внутри сервера, нет?  т.е.  запросы к api ucoz ограничены секундами..

Comment: @Maqsood, а зачем что отправлять сайту ucoz, можно открыть страницу message.html в фрейме и не на ней разместить скрипт, который будет отправлять запросы через comet в message.php.

Comment: @cyber_ua, я все понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Что именно не получилось ?
Вы учли что на сервер должен разрешать кроссдоменный запрос, [Cross-origin resource sharing](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) .

Все что вам нужно сделать это встроить на сайты ucoz js скрипт который будет отправлять запрос на нужный адрес, если используете jquery то все очень просто, если чистый js то можете воспользоваться готовым решением или [почитать](http://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-intro) .
Вот хорошая статья про [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Headers) (на английском).

Comment: @cyber_ua, благодарю! в википедии напомнило о JSONP, я думаю отправлять данные именно этим форматом, а на сайтах ucoz получать данные с jquery. Вот нюанс вышел: как узнать, что администратор прочел сообщение (получил данные) ? - нужно после прочтения, спрятать блок - до следующего сообщения..

Comment: @Maqsood, по моему, лучше делать это обычным нажатием на блок с сообщением — чтобы случайно не удалять прочтённое сообщение при ложном срабатывании "прочтения".